# Silverlight filter/class for cloud generation?

Tags: c#, silverlight-3.0, filter, cloud, hlsl

Silverlight filter/class for cloud generation? 
Some HLSL
or just C# class for generating clouds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do I understand correctly that you want to draw clouds using Silverlight? If so you could look at [this](http://kodierer.blogspot.com/2009/05/oscar-algorithm-silverlight-real-time.html) blog post. It shows a Silverlight implementation of Perlin Noise that is used to generate clouds.